# Limit on a number of SAML identity providers

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Is there a limit on a number of external SAML identity providers created under Security Controls > Single Sign-On Settings

Comment: I don't think there is a defined limit by Salesforce. [Multiple SSO](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.sso_saml_detail.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 2):

There's no limit. If there was, you'd find this in the documentation.